# Simultaneous recording & playback from MultiChannelMixer AudioUnit

Tags: ios, core-audio

I'm trying to create an app that plays several samples loaded from the files (similar to iPhoneMultichannelMixer sample app), simultaneously records user's input from the mic or line input and saves (records) everything in any stereo format to a file.

Architecturally, I have a Mixer AudioUnit that receives different samples as input, mixes them and plays back via IORemote. IORemote mic input is being captured by another callback for recording. The problem is - how do I record *both* the mic input and what is being played from the Mixer AudioUnit output bus?

Can I simply mix what I get from the mic into the same mixer and connect mixer both to IORemote as well as some other AudioUnit (which type?) that will handle recording of the mixed signal? Is it possible simultaneously? Should I do it sequentially - connect mixer first to a recording AudioUnit (which??) and then to IORemote for playback? Should / can I use AudioQueue for recording the output from the mixer?

I realize it's a lot of questions, but search didn't yield any positive results so appreciate any direction.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before.

They way I did it was by creating another bus in the mixer for the voice which render its data from the remoteIO, specifically from the microphone. Then add an AudioRenderNotify at the output of the mixer to capture all the audio combined. Within this callback I set a ExtAudioFileWriteAsync and Voila! all your audio combined and saved into a file.

You can even use compressed audio on the fly. AAC AppleLossless or even plain a simple LinearPCM (Wave, Aiff)